# Drag rect not working as expected

Tags: d3.js, svg, drag

I have created a d3 visualization that takes an json data, create a rect for each data point, and then displays the text in the rect. However, drag
 works only for the 1st rect.

I am wondering how to acts a natural drag action for each rect.

my codepen project:  https://codepen.io/moriakijp/project/editor/ZRnVwr

here is the code:

```
drawNumbers = layout => {
    const width = innerWidth;
    const height = width * 0.5;
    const margin = {
        top: height * 0.05,
        bottom: height * 0.05,
        left: width * 0.05,
        right: width * 0.05
    };

    d3.json(layout).then(data => {

    const colsize = data[data.length-1].col;
    const rowsize = data[data.length-1].row;
    const blocksize = colsize < rowsize ? 
            (width - margin.left - margin.right) / colsize: 
            (height - margin.left - margin.right) / rowsize;

        function dragstarted(d) {
        }

        function dragged(d) {
        d3
            .select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("x", (d.x = d3.event.x))
            .attr("y", (d.y = d3.event.y));
        d3
            .select(this)
            .select("text")
            .attr("x", (d.x = d3.event.x))
            .attr("y", (d.y = d3.event.y));
        }

        const dragended = (d) => {
        }

        const drag = d3
        .drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);

        const svg = d3
        .select("#heatmap")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .call(drag)

        svg
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", "block")
        .attr("class", "block")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => blocksize * (i % colsize)) // relative to 'svg'
        .attr("y", (d, i) => blocksize * (data[i].row - 1)) // relative to 'svg'
        .attr("width", blocksize)
        .attr("height", blocksize)
        .attr("fill", "#d00a")
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2")

        svg
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text(d => `${d.char}`)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => blocksize * (i % colsize))
        .attr("y", (d, i) => blocksize * (data[i].row - 1))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "#333")
        .attr("dx", blocksize / 2)
        .attr("dy", blocksize / 2)
        .style("font-size", blocksize / 2 );
    });
    };

    drawNumbers('number.json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't quite using the enter pattern correctly if you want to take "data, create a rect for each data point, and then displays the text in the rect."

Let's break down what you have:

```
const svg = d3
  .select("#heatmap")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(drag)
```

Here you select the element with id `heatmap` append an svg, and then enter a `g` for each item in your data array. As such, `svg` is a selection of three `g` elements, and you call the drag on these `g` elements.

Next you take this selection of three `g` elements and select child `g` elements. As there are no child `g` elements (this is an empty selection), entering and appending (`rect`s), creates three child rectangles for each `g` in the selection `svg`:

```
    svg          
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    ....
```

You do the same thing with the text. Now we have 9 rectangles and 9 texts, three each in each of the parent `g` elements (held the selection `svg`). Each of those parent `g` elements has a drag function that positions the first rectangle in it:

```
    d3
        .select(this)
        .select("rect")  // select first matching element
        .attr("x", (d.x = d3.event.x))
        .attr("y", (d.y = d3.event.y));
```

As each `g` has three rectangles, only the first one will be moved.

---

One solution would be to not do an enter cycle for each `g` in `svg`: your data is not nested, we already have a `g` for each item in the data array. So we just need to append a single text element and a single rect element to each `g`:

```
svg.append("rect").attr("x", function(d) {...
```

The data bound originally to the `g` is also bound to this child element, no need to rebind data. *Though, I'd rename `svg` to something else so that it is more reflective of its role and contents though*.

Overall this might look something like:

```
const g = d3
  .select("#heatmap")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
  .selectAll("g") 
  .data(data)
  .enter()      // create a g for each item in the data array
  .append("g")
  .call(drag)

  // add a rect to each g
  g.append("rect")
  .attr("id", "block")
  .attr("class", "block")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => blocksize * (i % colsize)) // relative to 'svg'
  .attr("y", (d, i) => blocksize * (data[i].row - 1)) // relative to 'svg'
  .attr("width", blocksize)
  .attr("height", blocksize)
  .attr("fill", "#d00a")
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2")

// add text to each g
g.append("text")
  .attr("id", "text")
  .attr("class", "text")
  .text(d => `${d.char}`)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => blocksize * (i % colsize))
  .attr("y", (d, i) => blocksize * (data[i].row - 1))
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "#333")
  .attr("dx", blocksize / 2)
  .attr("dy", blocksize / 2)
  .style("font-size", blocksize / 2 );
```

Here's a [running example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/bbdaba3de1e03814b0e863b68e05cc3b) with the above modification.